# QEmu shared folders for Debian Etch

Tags: debian, mount, qemu, shared-folders, virt-manager

I have to work with an old Debian release - Etch (4.0r9, kernel 2.6.33.7) - as the guest OS in QEmu/KVM. The host is Ubuntu 16.
I created a shared folder in Virtual Machine Manager.
However, when I try to mount it in the VM, I get the following error:

```
mount -t 9p -o trans=virtio /scratch/Host /scratch/Host
mount: unknown filesystem type '9p'
```

Does Debian Etch / this kernel support `9p` filesystem in principle? Perhaps with some additional commands, how to get it working?